# Pyspark write dataframe to parquet file format use variable name as directory which is not part of dataframe schema

Tags: pyspark, parquet

Is there any way in Pyspark to write dataframe to parquet file format use variable name as directory which is not part of dataframe schema.

**Code**

```
tables_list = ['abc','def','xyz']
for table_name in tables_list:
    df.write.parquet(os.path.join("s3://bucket/output/"), table_name)
```

**Error**

```
table_name(abc,def,xyz) is not part of the schema.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a syntax error. Your code should work if you move second parantheses to end of the line for following line

```
 df.write.parquet(os.path.join("s3://bucket/output/"), table_name)
```

I didn't try for s3 but code below creates an "abc" directory under "/tmp" on hdfs.

```
import os
tables_list = ['abc']
for table_name in tables_list:
    df.write.parquet(os.path.join("/tmp",table_name))
```

Comment: It is working fine now. thanks for the headsup.